# Bluetooth mouse/keyboard good on 18.04, fails on 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, bluetooth

I have a USB Bluetooth adapter that I use for mouse and keyboard. It works fine in 18.04, but does not generate any input on 20.04. The two machines are side by side, making it easy to compare.

(EDIT: looks like others are having trouble on 20.04 with this device. This question refers to the same Broadcom device ID: [Bluetooth problems using Logitech MX Master 3 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264454/bluetooth-problems-using-logitech-mx-master-3-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts) )

The device is "seen" (for some level of meaning of "seen") in both machines, it just doesn't generate input in the 20.04 system.

`usb-devices` produced this for the device under 20.04 (and the output in 18.04 looks the same at a as far as I can tell, aside from the particular bus it's on)

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=04 Prnt=15 Port=02 Cnt=03 Dev#= 18 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0b05 ProdID=17cb Rev=01.12
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=BCM20702A0
S:  SerialNumber=5CF37098ED95
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=btusb
I:  If#=0x3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

and `lsmod | grep btusb` shows this:

```
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
bluetooth             581632  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Again, I don't spot any difference between this (on the 20.04 system) and the output on the 18.04 machine where it works.

If I go into the Settings app, Bluetooth page, the 18.04 machine shows both the mouse and the keyboard, however, the equivalent page in 20.04 shows nothing, only "Unknown   Not Set Up" greyed out.

Can anyone help me get this working?

TIA
Toby

Comment: did you figure out the issue. I have the same issue on 20.04

Comment: No, I got no responses, failed to come up with any ideas. I had to abandon the bluetooth keyboard and replaced it with an older wireless type. Hoping something happens that might change the situation so I can go back to the better (bluetooth) keyboard.